# Adding custom meta tags for every different page in Joomla

Tags: joomla2.5, meta-tags

I use Joomla 2.5. I want to set a meta tag property named "com.silverpop.pagename" for each page (article) in my website. For example, my homepage will have:

```
<meta name="com.silverpop.pagename" content="Home Page" />
```

My blog will have:

```
<meta name="com.silverpop.pagename" content="Blog" />
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the header. This can be done editing

> JOOMLA_ROOT\libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer\head.php

Here you can change the behaviour of header

Comment: Editing the Joomla core was never the correct way to do this. Avoid at all costs!

Answer (score 2):

I was suffering with the same problem when I had to add Facebook Open graph META Tags on my Joomla project.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>;
```

I had included this code on my Joomla template and it worked for me, please have a look:

```
# add Facebook tags
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addCustomTag("<meta property='og:type' content='article'/>");
```

Also you can refer this [**Link**](http://www.robertwent.com/blog/joomla/69-adding-facebook-opengraph-meta-tags-to-a-joomla-3-template).

Hope it will help others.